# Text in graphic with easeljs

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, easeljs

I'm using the easel.js library (src: [easeljs library](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS)) and the example game that you can find here: [easel js space game example](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS/demos/game).

As you can see there are spacerocks. These are formed like this:

```
this.graphics.beginStroke("#FFFFFF");
```

Now my question is if you can put a word in them with the graphics class?
I would like to have a text in it like "@BachelorGDM".

Now I'm trying to do this with "beginBitmapFill" like this:

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap("http://nielsvroman.be/twitter/root/easeljs/image.png");
    this.graphics.beginBitmapFill(bitmap);
```

but I always get a Type eror. Error can be watched here:
http://nielsvroman.be/twitter/root/game.html
(In console)

Comment: Page 11 of their demos has an option for adding text to the scene.  Page 6 of their demos shows moving a text div around to follow the position of other items.  Set the div's background transparent, and you should be able to get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this : http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Text.html

Example:

```
var text = new createjs.Text("Hello World", "20px Arial", "#ff7700");
text.x = 100;
text.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
```

Or, you could use a sprite-sheet with the alphabet, numbers and other symbols you want to use, and from those sprites you build a graphic with the text and use that graphic.

You would load the bitmap into a bitmap object like this:

```
var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap("http://nielsvroman.be/twitter/root/easeljs/image.png%22");
```

Comment: I'm trying now with graphics.beginBitMapFill like this:
this.graphics.beginBitmapFill("http://nielsvroman.be/twitter/root/easeljs/image.png"); But I always get a Type error. (Edited begin post)

Comment: spacerock.js, line 53, you still use img which is a string.

Comment: Also, new problems ought to be different questions otherwise your question has less value for future visitors.

Comment: Changed it, was working online. Now it's also online .. Still error

Comment: .Bitmap is not part of createjs, I assume that EaselJs was not correctly loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32100/discussion-between-tomdemuyt-and-niels123)

Comment: I answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221853/graphics-bitmapfill-typeerror/17237662#17237662 -- use an Image, and not a Bitmap

Answer (score 1):

`beginBitmapFill` expects `Image`, not `Bitmap`. Correct example would be:

```
var img = new Image("myimage.png");
new Graphics().beginBitmapFill(img);
```